# Getting error when importing XML file to SQL table through a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to store an XML file in SQL. I've tried doing the below:

1. Creating a sql table to store the data in it:

```
    USE tempdb;  
    CREATE TABLE T1(XmlCol xml);  
    GO
```

2. Inserting my XML file in SQL:

```
    INSERT T1  
      SELECT CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn, 2) FROM   
        OPENROWSET(Bulk 'C:\Temp\sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) [rowsetresults];
```

However, when I run the command I get this error:

> 'C:\Temp\sample.xml' contains an unsupported prefix. Retry with
> supported connector prefix.

I've trying googling this error but nothing comes up.

Has anyone come across this error before? What does it mean?

Thank you in advance!

I tried searching online for the error but there aren't many resources out there that help me understand the error. At least I want to try figure out what the error means and go from there.

EDIT: The sample xml file looks like this:

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: The error is due to a namespace issue in the xml.  It looks like a namespace in the xml is missing a URL attribute.  Was the xml validated by the people who generated the xml?

Comment: I am trying to test out the code with a sample file that looks like this (but no luck). The file that I'm using wasn't validated by the person who created it:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Root>  
          <ProductDescription ProductModelID="5">  
             <Summary>Some Text</Summary>  
          </ProductDescription>  
</Root>

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Check with `SELECT @@VERSION`. Management Studio is just a GUI and its version is largely irrelevant.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Azure

Comment: Well there you go -- why would you expect Azure to be able to read a file on your local C: drive? Azure can only read from Azure blobs. Upload your file first.